# Calculating Win Streaks

Tags: vba, excel, excel-formula, formula

I'm tracking players' performances in a game and I want to automatically generate the **current win streak** of players. Additionally, I also want to track the **highest win streak** of the players. I've tried looking at [this](https://exceljet.net/formula/longest-winning-streak), [this](http://www.excelarticles.com/LE10ePub-150.html) and [that](https://www.thespreadsheetguru.com/blog/2014/6/29/formulas-to-calculate-longest-current-win-streaks), but I cannot seem to tweak the formula to suit my scenario.
[image: Speadsheet of Tracked Statistics]

There are 8 possible values that can be input into the cells:

1. Attack Won
2. Attack Lost
3. Both Attacks Won
4. Both Attacks Lost
5. Win, then Lost
6. Lost, then Win
7. Did not Participate
8. Kicked

I would like the formula to calculate the win streak such that Player1 has a current win streak of 8, Player2 has a current win streak of 7, Player3 has a current win streak of 3, so on and so forth.

**What is a formula I can use, without using VBA to generate the respective win streaks?**

---

### Additional Case Studies

**Sample Game Results**

```
Player  |    War 1    |       War 2         |        War 3        |      War 4       |        War 5
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
PlayerA | Attack Won  |   Both Attacks Won  |   Win, then Lost    |    Attack Won    |     Attack Won
PlayerB | Attack Won  |     Attack Lost     |   Lost, then Win    | Both Attacks Win |     Attack Lost
PlayerC | Attack Won  | Did not Participate | Did not Participate | Both Attacks Won |     Attack Won
PlayerD | Attack Lost |     Attack Lost     | Did not Participate | Win, then Lost   | Did not Participate
```

**Desired Win Streaks Output**

```
Player  | Highest Win Streak | Current Win Streak
--------------------------------------------------
PlayerA |        3           |         2
PlayerB |        3           |         0
PlayerC |        4           |         4
PlayerD |        1           |         0
```

Thanks!

Comment: You should investigate the countif() function.

Comment: @SolarMike I'm not sure how to use the countif() function to look further down the row and stop when it detects a "Loss"

Comment: This is more complicated than it looks. How many different entries count as a Win towards a streak? Attack Won/ Both Attacks Won /Win, then Lost   (3 possible entries)? And does the streak continue if there are did not participates between wins? ie. win did not p win would be 1 or 2?

Comment: Does Both Attack Won count as 2 wins?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think your given case studies need more explanation.

VBA:

Assumptions:

1. It counts across did not participate (DNP), i.e. if you have DNP in between Wins you pick up your win count from where it was before the DNP.
2. It ignores DNPs at the start until the first Win.
3. Both Attacks Win is considered 2 wins. If not then comment out 3 lines
   `Case "both attacks won"`,  `winStreak = winStreak + 2` and `currentWinStreak = currentWinStreak + 2`. It will enter the `Case Else` and add 1.
4. Win-then-lose is considered a win then restarts the win count.
5. Lose-then-win resets the win count and adds 1 to current count.
6. StartCell is the column C value for the row to use in the calculation.

**Code:**

```
Option Explicit

Public Sub WriteOutValues()
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Dim ws As Worksheet, currentCell As Range

    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")
    With ws
         For Each currentCell In .Range("C2", .Range("C2").End(xlDown))
            currentCell.Offset(8, -1) = GetWinStreak(currentCell)(0)
            currentCell.Offset(8, 0) = GetWinStreak(currentCell)(1)
        Next currentCell
    End With
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub

Public Function GetWinStreak(ByVal startCell As Range) As Variant

    With startCell.Parent
        Dim loopRange As Range
        Set loopRange = .Range(startCell, startCell.End(xlToRight))
        Dim winTerms()
        winTerms = Array("attack won", "both attacks won", "win, then lost", "lost, then win")
        Dim winStreak As Long, highestWinStreak As Long, currentWinStreak As Long, currentCell As Range
        Dim testValue As String

        For Each currentCell In loopRange
            testValue = LCase$(Trim$(currentCell.Value))
            If testValue = "did not participate" And winStreak = 0 Then GoTo NextLine

            If Not IsError(Application.Match(testValue, winTerms, 0)) Then
                Select Case testValue
                Case "both attacks won"
                    winStreak = winStreak + 2
                    currentWinStreak = currentWinStreak + 2
                    If highestWinStreak < winStreak Then highestWinStreak = winStreak
                Case "win, then lost"
                    winStreak = winStreak + 1
                    If highestWinStreak < winStreak Then highestWinStreak = winStreak
                    winStreak = 0
                    currentWinStreak = 0
                Case "lost, then win"
                    winStreak = 0
                    currentWinStreak = 1
                    winStreak = winStreak + 1
                    If highestWinStreak < winStreak Then highestWinStreak = winStreak
                Case Else
                    winStreak = winStreak + 1
                    currentWinStreak = currentWinStreak + 1
                    If highestWinStreak < winStreak Then highestWinStreak = winStreak
                End Select
            ElseIf testValue = "did not participate" And winStreak > 0 Then
            Else
                winStreak = 0
                currentWinStreak = 0
            End If
NextLine:
        Next currentCell
    End With

    GetWinStreak = Array(highestWinStreak, currentWinStreak)
End Function
```

Alt + F11 to open the VBE and right click insert standard module in project and code goes in there.

**Code in module :**

[image: Code in module]

**Output:**

[image: Output]

**Formulas:**

Flawed at present e.g. 1) BW (Both Attacks Won) counts as 1 point 2) Count not maintained across Did Not Contribute 3) Doesn't correctly handle WTL and LTW. Included as my best attempt so far that maybe someone can improve upon. Image above does not represent output of formulas. See image below.

So depending on what counts towards a win amend the following:

```
(C2:J2="W") + (C2:J2="BW") + (C2:J2="WTL")
```

In the above W is Win, BW is Both Win , WTL is Win Then Lose. Assume these all contribute to a winning streak. Otherwise, remove the term that doesn't count.

In B2 goes, and drag down rows:

```
=MAX(FREQUENCY(IF((C2:J2="W") + (C2:J2="BW") + (C2:J2="WTL"),COLUMN($C$1:$J$1)-COLUMN($C$1)+1),IF((C2:J2="W") + (C2:J2="BW") + (C2:J2="WTL"),0,COLUMN($C$1:$J$1)-COLUMN($C$1)+1)))
```

You enter it as an array formula, meaning your press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Enter</kbd>, to enter the formula in the cell and {} braces should appear at either end of the formula.

[image: Data]

Comment: Neat, but does it have to be entered as an array formula?

Comment: @solarmike yes it does

Comment: @QHarr I was thinking along these lines, but the tricky part comes when there are WTL and LTW.... giving a simple example: `Attack Won | Attack Won | Win, then Lost | Attack Won` has a current win streak of 1 (W,W,W,L,**W**) and a highest win streak of 3 (**W,W,W**,L,W), whereas `Attack Won | Attack Won | Lost, then Win | Attack Won` has a current win streak of 2 (W,W,L,**W,W**) and a highest win streak of 2 (**W,W**,L,W,W **OR** W,W,L,**W,W**). So how is the formula able to cater for these scenarios? P.S. bolded letters are the results taken into consideration for each scenario.

Comment: Formula will give the right result I think as W,W,W,L,W would be 3. It does the max consecutive streak. Not the total overall.

Comment: Oh...I think I see what you mean. WTL counts as two results as does BW? So WTL would be WL so 1 and BW would WW so 2?

Comment: @QHarr yes, BW is WW. The win streak also maintains count across Did not Participate.. my example above in the previous comment just serves as an emphasis for the difference between WTL and LTW

Comment: Ok. My vba answer should do what I think you need. Let me know if you want help with it.

Comment: @QHarr thanks very much.. I made a few changes after seeing a few minor bugs in the program output, adding the line `If highestWinStreak < winStreak Then highestWinStreak = winStreak` into the "both attacks won" case (this is added to cater for situations where "both attacks won" was the latest entry in the spreadsheet, which caused the "Highest win streak" to not be displayed accurately). Also I changed the line in the case "lost, then win" to be `currentWinStreak = 1` because of some scenarios where the currentWinStreak did not reinitialise to 0. awesome job overall, thanks! :)

Comment: Please feel free to edit in the changes. And good spot. I definitely shouldn't have missed the both win case!

Answer (score 0):

So, without doing them all, as you have several different results (you may want to re-consider how you record data...), you can make use of countifs(), using War 1 as an example:
[image]

Once you have a list of win streak results max() is one way but large() also offers more flexibility i.e. largest and next largest...